# SharePoint calendar CSS is not showing properly

Tags: css, sharepoint

I'm working on SharePoint calendar it is working fine on another site but its not loading CSS in my project showing the below error in chrome console. Do you guys have any idea how to fix this.

```
Refused to apply style from '/sites/new/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx?ctag=5' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

[image]

Comment: that mean that your css file isn't recognized as truly css content , 
Is it minified ? try to check if there are  comment in the file then remove them ?